# Cloudinary search on php

Tags: php, search, cloudinary

I'm facing this problem with Cloudinary on php:

I've copy/paste the documentation of search :

```
 $result = \Cloudinary\search   ->expression('resource_type:image')  
 ->sort_by('public_id','desc')   ->max_results(30)   ->execute();
```

And it returns this error :

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)

I've tried with uploading and it works fine, the syntax of uploading is quite different:

```
$result = \Cloudinary\Uploader::upload($file, $options = array());
```

But if tried accesing this way to search and it gives scope's errors :

```
$result = \Cloudinary\Search :: execute();
```

> Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in
>   /var/www/mymoda.tj.net/htdocs/2.0/inc/cloudinary/Search.php on line 78

Answer (score 0):

Try to add parentheses after search(`search()`) since it is a function:

```php
 $result = \Cloudinary\search()->expression('resource_type:image')  
 ->sort_by('public_id','desc')->max_results(30)->execute();
```

Maybe they misspelled it in the documentation.